# IF commands in a batch file

Tags: command-line, script, batch

I'm writing a small batch file to replace users' themes and charts in Office. I have the below batch file that works just fine.

```
cd c:\documents and settings\%username%\application data\microsoft\templates
echo Y | rmdir charts /s
mkdir charts
echo Y | del "c:\documents and settings\%username%\application data\microsoft\templates\document themes\*.*"

net use o: \\servername\sms
copy "o:\ppt themes\charts\*.*" "c:\documents and settings\%username%\application data\microsoft\templates\charts"
copy "o:\ppt themes\Document Themes\*.*" "c:\documents and settings\%username%\application data\microsoft\templates\document themes"

c:
net use o: /delete
```

Now what I want is the above to only run if it hasn't run before as we'll be pushing this out to all users for around 2 weeks to catch people that aren't in every day.

Is there any way to begin the command with something to look for one of the new themes/charts already pushed down, and if it's present, then have it not run?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I'm pretty new to these batch files.

Comment: A few unrelated comments: 1) `rmdir /s/q somedirectory` - no unneeded prompts; 2) you can `copy` directly out of `\\servername\share\path\file`, so `net use` is unnecessary.

Comment: It's also possible to use the `/q` flag with the `del` command too.

Comment: @afrazier: Yes, but `del` will leave the empty subdirectories behind.

Comment: Ah I tried to copy directly out of the server share and it threw up some error when I viewed it with Pause. I can't remember what the error was, though. I'll give it another shot, though, to try and tidy it up. Thanks =)

Comment: @grawity: I know, but the question has an `echo Y | del C:\Path\*` statement, so I thought the asker might find that tidbit useful.

Answer (score 2):

> if exist path\to\some\file\here  goto end
>
> .... the rest of your script here ....
>   ....
>   ....
>
> :end

Note the colon preceding the label ('end', in this case) - it's important.  The actual label word, 'end', isn't magic; any word (used on both places) would do.

Comment: In `cmd.exe` you can use `goto :eof` instead, which doesn't need a label.

Comment: This approach assumes some unique "version" file that you'd push out also. (Before and after the script runs, files exist in \charts and \document themes)

Comment: Thanks JRobert, I'll give that a shot when I'm back in on Monday.

Comment: RJFalconer: Of course just any old file wouldn't do; the presence of the file tested for needs to uniquely indicate that the update has taken place.

Comment: The files being pushed down will have unique names not present before the push, so that shouldn't be a problem.